# If the distinguishing advantage of A wrt distribution D_n, E_n is 1/poly(n) with probability .1, then are they not computationally indistinguishable?

Tags: indistinguishability

As in the title, but to make more clear:

If, with probability 0.1, an algorithm A can distinguish between two ensembles D_n, E_n (indexed by sec. paramater n), then are D_n, E_n not computationally indistinguishable?

More generally, is it true that, $$\Pr_A\Big[\big|\Pr_{x\sim D_n}[A(x) = 1] - \Pr_{x\sim E_n}[A(x) = 1]\big|>\epsilon\Big] = 0.1 \implies \big|\Pr_{x\sim D_n}[A(x) = 1] - \Pr_{x\sim E_n}[A(x) = 1]\big|>\epsilon/10$$

Comment: Are you claiming that $\epsilon/10$ is not negligible? You need an upper bound not lower.